# How to avoid Delphi fatal error F2051 when not all programmers have access to complete source

Tags: delphi

In our team new programmers does not get access to all the source of our application.
As long as they have to access program forms that depend only classes they can access the source, all is ok. When they have to use other classes from units they have only the .dcu, they get the F2051 error when the classes in the dcu change their interface.

Is there a clean way to get both ?

- possibility to hide part of the source from new programmers
- avoid the F2051 error when the classes in the "hidden" units change

I searched for a way to compile the Delphi code to a intermediate representation the way to hide the sources but to permit compilation, but I did not find anything.

Comment: This sounds like a great place to work. Where programmers aren't allowed to see the source code!

Comment: the DCU is the _intermedaite_ representation you're looking for. You just have to update all the dcu's in programmers stations after interface changes. You can easily automate that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Dilbert-esquely great place? ^-^

Comment: Why not allow them to see the source, just not commit any changes?

Comment: Not showing new programmers the whole source code and expecting them to do anything other than be lost and confused forever seems dumb to me.

Answer (score 8):

You have to compile the code after the interface changes, and distribute the new .dcu to each programmer that needs to use it without source, and then they need to rebuild their applications. There is absolutely no other way to do it; the compiler requires it if there are changes in the interface.

Answer (score 4):

For those "hidden" units, put the *.dcu* in the source control along with the *.pas* and make sure they are updated and in sync.
The "authorized" developers will fetch the new *.pas*, while the underlings will only see and fetch the *.dcu*.

If you really want to go that route of having 2nd class programmers, you have to do the management work that go with it.

That being said I'm personally more often that not stepping into the VCL source code when chasing a bug and trying to understand what's going on.
And I really don't like not having it (like with some low level Delphi SKU)

Comment: There are no "dumbed down" Delphi SKUs. There are lower level ones (Starter) that don't include all the features of Professional and above SKUs, and they're sold at a lower price because they don't. If you want the features, buy the actual version. If you don't want to spend the money, don't complain about what you didn't buy. :-) With that being said, SO isn't really the place to complain about the decisions made by the software producers, and including it reduces the quality of your answer.

Comment: @KenWhite, it does not reduce the general fact that not giving the source to the developers is not considered clever by a lot of people, including me. And I have always believed that having the Delphi source available since D1 was one of the best decision made by Borland...  Also, I'm not complaining for my particular case, as my personal versions of Delphi are mostly Architect ones.

Comment: @KenWhite, That being said. I agree that SO is not the place to comment on Delphi SKUs segmentation and worthiness (although that could be argued). Changed the wording anyway, as the main point is "Read the Source!".

Comment: ;-) In Delphi 1, the source was an extra add on (don't remember the SKU name) for anything less than the Architect/Enterprise SKUs; you had to pay as much for it as you did for the first version of Delphi Pro. My personal SKU has always been Professional, as it has everything that I need (or I have third party add-ons/components). I never had the source for D1, though; it shipped with `.int` files so you could see the interface sections. I survived. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create a stable binary unit that you can share with people you don't trust to read your source code, why don't you put the "secret" bits into a DLL and then load that DLL from the rest of the code.

It's called an "Application Binary Interface", either done natively with plain old pascal procedures exported from a DLL, or with COM Interfaces and a COM type-library.

Delphi has both DLL and BPL technology, to help you create something that isn't source code, but which has a stable ABI, and which will help you avoid whatever crazy little mess it sounds like you've got on your hands right now.

Comment: With a DLL, the IDE will not be able to show the unit interface in the same way as with DCUs (CodeInsight).

Comment: That's the whole point. Real `INTERFACES` (binary stable) or DLL export interfaces are the only thing that is exposed in my suggestion.

Comment: But there are things CodeInsight allows you to show (validly accessible things) from a compiled DCU that would NOT be visible from a DLL containing the same code, which is the point mjn was making. (And your question does not address the question asked, either; it offers a comment on an alternate solution.)